# supervised data linkage in R. How do I return the linked rows?

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am doing data linkage of data sets using R and the package RecordLinkage. I am doing a supervised linkage, and I can see that there are 50 records that the algorithm has matched.

```
> train <- getMinimalTrain(compare.dedup(RLdata500, 
identity=identity.RLdata500, blockfld=list(1,3)))
> rpairs1<-RLBigDataDedup(RLdata500, identity=identity.RLdata500)
> classif<-trainSupv(train, "rpart", minsplit=2)
> result<-classifySupv(classif, rpairs1)
```

============================================================================

> getTable(result)
>                  classification
>       true status      N      P      L
>                 0 124696      0      4
>                 1      2      0     48
>   summary(result)
>       RLResult object

```
RLBigDataDedup, Deduplication object

Number of records: 500 
Attributes: fname_c1, fname_c2, lname_c1, lname_c2, by, bm, bd 
Blocking definition:  
Number of record pairs: 124750 
Number of matches: 50 
Number of non-matches: 124700 

Number of detected links: 52 
Number of detected possible links: 0 
Number of detected non-links: 124698
```

I want to be able to see what the 52 rows that link to other rows are. How do I do this?